# How to get the maximum count of two lists obtained by projecting two properties from a collection of a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, optimization

Say I have the follwing code:

```
   Private Sub Calculate()
    Dim basket As New List(Of AppleOrangePair)
    For i = 1 To 10000
        Dim pair As New AppleOrangePair
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then pair.Orange.IsRotten = True
        basket.Add(pair)
    Next

    Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch
    stopwatch.Start()
    Dim edibleAppleCount = basket.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(pair) Not pair.Apple.IsRotten)
    Dim edibleOrangeCount = basket.AsEnumerable.Count(Function(pair) Not pair.Orange.IsRotten)

    LargestCount = Math.Max(edibleAppleCount, edibleOrangeCount)
    Time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

    stopwatch.Stop()

End Sub

Class Fruit
    Property IsRotten As Boolean
End Class

Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit
End Class

Class Orange
    Inherits Fruit
End Class

Class AppleOrangePair
    Public Sub New()
        Apple = New Apple
        Orange = New Orange
    End Sub

    Public Property Apple As Apple
    Public Property Orange As Orange
End Class
```

This code is pretty fast, but it requires an iteration of the basket twice. Can this code be rewritten so that the basket is interated just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in our rush to try newer technology, we overlook the tried and true.  In my tests a simple For loop was faster by a good 30% than either of the LINQ options:

```
    Dim applecount, orangecount As Long
    For I = 0 To basket.Count - 1
        applecount += Convert.ToInt64(Not basket(I).Apple.IsRotten)
        orangecount += Convert.ToInt64(Not basket(I).Orange.IsRotten)
    Next
```

Comment: A boaring, but very fast answer :-) It takses just 590 ms to complete as opposed to the 1800 and 2800ms of the other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Aggregate` method and implement the conditional `Count` inside it:

```
Dim edibleCount = basket.Aggregate(New With {.Apple = 0, .Orange = 0}, _
                                   Function(acc, pair) New With {
                                       .Apple = If(pair.Apple.IsRotten, acc.Apple, acc.Apple + 1),
                                       .Orange = If(pair.Orange.IsRotten, acc.Orange, acc.Orange + 1)
                                   })

results.Add(Math.Max(edibleCount.Apple, edibleCount.Orange))
```

Quick performance tests show it's about 25% faster than your approach.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. However, on my system it is not faster, even a little slower.

Comment: Are you sure you test in on Release build, without VS attached? I've tested it multiple times, with different numbers of runs within test and results were quite repeatable.

Comment: In release build without VS attached it is even nearly twice as slow, though the program speeds up a 100% as compared to running it from the IDE.

Comment: That's really interesting. Here is the entire code I'm using to test that: http://pastebin.com/zt9CnD3L

Comment: With that code your solution is indeed faster (1800ms vs 2800ms), but only when it is run detached from the IDE.

Comment: IDE adds a lot of stuff to the execution, even when you run it in `Release` mode. That's why you should never do performance tests directly from IDE.